# Is $X^*$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X^*$ be the quotient space obtained by the partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into singletons and the subset of integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Is $X^*$ metrizable?

Answer (score 3):

No, this quotient is not first countable at the class corresponding to the class $\mathbb{Z}$, so in particular it's not metrisable.

This can be shown using a diagonal argument: suppose that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a countable local base $U_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ in the quotient topology. $U_n$ open  means that $q^{-1}[U_n]$ must be a normal open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the reals, so we can assume it is is of the form

$$q^{-1}[U_n]=\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} (m-r^{(n)}_m, m+r^{(n)}_m)$$ for some sequence of reals $r^{(n)}_m < \frac12$ (or else shrink the open sets slightly, which doesn't affect their "local base-ness").

Then the set $$O=q[\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} (m-\frac12 r^{(|m|)}_m, m+\frac12 r^{|m|}_m)]$$

is open in the quotient, contains $\mathbb{Z}$ but no elements $U_n$, so these cannot form a local base, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you @Henno Brandsma. So in general, if a space is not first countable, it is not metrizable? Why is that?

Comment: @abeliangrape because all metrisable spaces are first countable: if $d$ is a compatible metric, then the $d$-balls around $x$ with radii $\frac{1}{n}$ form a countable local base at $x$, for any $x$. And $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$.

Comment: Thank you. The missing knowledge for me was “all metrisable spaces are first countable.” Thank you for including the proof of this fact as well.